# Have you got any ID on you? vs. Do you have any ID?

Tags: prepositions

I was recently watching a British video on You tube in which the guy making the video asks a girl if she has got any Id on her. I have heard the sentence "Have u got" being used before but I have never heard or observed the preposition "On" being used when asking about the possession. I really want to know if it is used by the native speakers of Britain only or even  Americans use it nowadays.

Comment: Yes, to have an ID on you. To have any money on you. Very standard. Both varieties of English. "On you" means with you at the moment. You might have an ID but you might not have it with you at a particular time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to have an ID on you. To have any money on you. Very standard. Both varieties of English. "On you" means with you at the moment. You might have an ID but you might not have it with you at a particular time. – Lambie